# Add CSS And JS files dynamically with Jade and Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm in a scenario where I'm going to render a page with Jade with following code

```
var media_files = { js_files: [
    {type: "text/javascript", src:"/app/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"}
    //..and it keeps adding
],
css_files: [
    {media:"all", src:"/app/public/css/style.css"}
    //..and it keeps adding
]
};
exports.index = function(req,res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Home', media_files: media_files }); //this will render the page
};
```

Expected result is it is going to print all js and css files in the header, this is what my jade looks like:

```
!!!5
html
  head
    title #{title} - My Site
    each key, file in media_files
      if(key == 'css_files')
        link(rel='stylesheet', src=file["src"], media=file["media"])
```

My question is none of the media files is printed, can someone give me a solution? (Personally i think using JSON is better, but I also have no idea how to do it, documentation about this is not much).

Comment: first correct your link syntax from src to href: `<link rel='stylesheet' href='/style.css'>` ~and double check it is not printed into the source using your f12 debugger or something.~ edit: @amberlamps is right, you're only iterating through the keys `js_files, css_files` and not iterating through the `files` array objecs

Answer (score 1):

You are not accessing the properties correctly. Try the following:

```
each key, files in media_files
  if(key == 'css_files')
    each file in files
      link(rel='stylesheet', href=file["src"], media=file["media"])
```

Plato is right, use `href` instead of `src`.

Comment: i changed to href already, still not working,`each key, files in media_files
      if(key == 'css_files')
        each file in files
          link(rel='stylesheet', href=file["href"], media=file["media"])`